# PHP / MySQL - Get Results from table1 based on count from table 2

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 tables, table1 and table2 which are linked by id (table1) and b_id (table2).

table1 has keyword data which I look for to grab a relevant result (just a simple %like%) (id, keyword_data).

table2 simple records views the result has got, (id, b_id, b_date)

I want to select the record with the least views by default and limit this to 7 results each time.

I have got the below but I know it doesn't look right!

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE keyword_data LIKE '%xxxx%' INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.b_id WHERE ORDER BY COUNT(table2.id) ASC LIMIT 7;
```

Thanks

Comment: can share table records and expected output with that records

Answer (score 1):

Errors are

- ORDER BY COUNT(table2.id) will be treated like 'ORDER BY 8' as COUNT(table2.id) results a numeric value
- And you have two 'WHERE' clauses.
- Condition is placed in wrong position in the query.

A corrected version(as per my understanding of logic).

```
SELECT distinct(A.id),A.keyword_data,(select count(table2.b_id) from table2 where table2.b_id=A.id) as count FROM table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B ON A.id = B.b_id WHERE A.keyword_data LIKE '%test%' order by count asc LIMIT 7
```

Comment: This works well with the exception of the load time becoming really long, I was wonder if the limit need moved?

Comment: thanks for the reply - forgot to add a thanks above ^

Comment: you are welcome. Are you working with really large tables? If yes, try indexing or other methods to make the search faster. it took only 0.00087 seconds on my table1 with 10 rows and table2 with 15 rows(both tables have no other columns other than those mentioned in the query).